# What do I need to know to fix this bug? LINGO PLAYER

Tags: javascript, api, nodes, video-subtitles

I am a language learner and I've come across a video player called "Lingo Player" which is supposed to help language learners learn while watching movies, series, etc, with subtitles.
The software has been out for a while and still available for download (you can download it here: https://oaprograms.github.io/lingo-player/), but it is not working as it was supposed to, probably due to the lack of updates in years.
It is a VLC-based player and as a video player, it works just fine, it plays the videos as it should.

But its tools meant for language learners are not working as it should:
It should show dictionary definitions above the words when you hover the mouse on them.

All I want here is someone that could help me find out WHAT I need to know in order to fix this software.

I see I probably need to now JavaScript as it has a low programmed in Java, but how do I crack it open? 
How do I change its codes? What softwares do I need to have in order to open Lingo Player and try to fix its codes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at the repo [Github](https://github.com/oaprograms/lingo-player#used-technologies) they explain what things you need to setup to start developing in this project, mostly you need to know javascript, you can start following their steps to getting started